# Inserting list to tables column (postgre)

Tags: python, postgresql, datatables

I am trying to "normalize" some data that I retrieve from an API, but it doesn't seem to work

Any pointers?

Ok after some corrections

```
def set_column():
    column_list = []
    connection = psycopg2.connect("postgres://postgres:banana_2@localhost:5432/postgres")
    connection.autocommit = True

    crs = connection.cursor()

    crs.execute("SELECT * FROM raw LIMIT 200")

    records = crs.fetchall()
    print(records)

    for record in records:
        try:
            animal = record[1].get("animal")
            breed = animal['breed']['breed_component']
            print(breed)

            column_list.append(breed)
        except Exception as e:
                pass
        finally:
            return column_list



def insert_to_column():

    connection = psycopg2.connect("postgres://postgres:banana_2@localhost:5432/postgres")
    connection.autocommit = True
    crs = connection.cursor()

    insert_q = """
     INSERT INTO data_warehouse (breed)
       SELECT j FROM unnest((%s)::text[]) AS j;
    """
    data = set_column()
    data = str(data)
    for d in data:
        crs.execute(insert_q, d)
```

It returns :

```
LINE 3:        SELECT j FROM unnest(('[')::text[]) AS j;
                                     ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

How do I overcome this? My approach might be wrong altogether because the table I am retrieving the data has about 1M rows. But how could I make this one work?

Answer (score 0):

The url response is valid JSON that contains an array. Leave Postgres to split it into elements. Just pass `response` as text to the query below. BTW what is the data type of `raw_dog.raw_data`? You may need to typecast `j`.

```
insert_q = """
 INSERT INTO raw_dog (raw_data)
   SELECT j FROM jsonb_array_elements((%s)::jsonb) AS j;
"""
crs.execute(insert_q, response)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The data type of raw_dog.raw_data is jsonb!

Comment: Then you do not need a cast.